# Svg is not being rendered on safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, svg, safari

I'm using some svg tags on my website, and they work just fine on google chrome but not working the way they are supposed to on safari.

I tried looking it up, but everyone had an Image tag in their svg tag which isn't my case, and the solution they had didn't work.
I tried to change the tag to instead of `<svg>` `<object>`
so yeah would really appreciate the help regarding this issue.

Here is my code:

```
  <svg id="myClass2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
          <defs>
            <filter id="gooey">
              <feGaussianBlur
                in="SourceGraphic"
                stdDeviation="5"
                result="blur"
              />
              <feColorMatrix
                in="blur"
                type="matrix"
                values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9"
                result="highContrastGraphic"
              />
              <feComposite
                in="SourceGraphic"
                in2="highContrastGraphic"
                operator="atop"
              />
            </filter>
          </defs>
        </svg>
 <button id="gooey-button">
              <text x="147" y="227" fill="#000">
                Resume
              </text>
              <span class="bubbles">
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
                <span class="bubble"></span>
              </span>
            </button>
```

This is where filter is being applied in the sass file:-

```
//.sass

#gooey-button 
    
    position: absolute
    top: 54%
    background-size: cover
    right: -300px
    margin-right: 400px
    max-width: 430px
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%)
    z-index: 2
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3))

    width: 110px
    height: 45px
    font-size: 20px
    border: none
    filter: url('#gooey')
    background-color: #61ca37
```

Here is how it looks like on google chrome and safari.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is a filter. We'd need to also see where this filter is applied on (with the CSS code).

Comment: I just editted my question, please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you